# how to handle filter authorization in servlet filter

Tags: java, web, filter, authorization, servlet-filters

I am facing filter authentication problem,  I have put filter authentication to authenticate that user is allowed to access application or not but problem is that i am developing APIs of that web application and if user is not logged in on web my API does not work it redirect to user login,how to handle this, i tried many ways to handle this issue but no fruit full result found.

Here is my web.xml:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.web.product.login.AuthorizationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

here is authorization filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;


    UserLoginBean auth = (UserLoginBean) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");




    System.out.println("req.getRequestURI()="+req.getRequestURI());


    if ((auth != null && auth.isLoggedIn()) 
            || req.getRequestURI().startsWith("/Product/UserLogin.xhtml")
            ||  req.getRequestURI().startsWith("/Product/javax.faces.resource") 
                     ){

        System.out.println("Filter Success");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Filter failure");

         HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/UserLogin.xhtml");


    }
}
```

Comment: @Kukeltje sir actually i am using prime faces and maven that's why i tag them, My problem is that i am developing APIs of my project but my APIs are not working until and unless i am login on my web System, without web login my APIs not working, if i run API and not login on web it redirect on login page first due to of filter, If i remove filter APIs working fine

Comment: @Kukeltje sir i can not switch to any other platform. simple problem is if a put authorization, it does not allow to access APIs  directly without login, if i remover authorization i can access APIs directly but  need is that i have to put authorization and  i can access APIs directly. You got my point?

Comment: Do you need security in your APIs? Are your APIs Rest?

Comment: @Pablo Bastidas  not got your point

Comment: How do you access your APIs??

Comment: @Pablo Bastidas  directly in URL 

i,e:
http://localhost:8080/Product/Search?USER_NAME=my&PASSWORD=my45&SEARCH=m&selectedCountryId=1&userStatus=0&methodType=getFilteredProfiles